# Enity Framework revertable migrations with data changes?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If you create a migration with just table structure changes, you're sure you can revert the migration on ease since it has `Up()` and `Down()` methods that are there for it.

But what if we have some data changes which don't seem to be revertable?

For example, now I have a nullable column with `Enum` values in it.

```
Paid column
---
Paid = 0
PaidTill = 1
NotPaid = 2
(+ NULL value)
```

so there are 4 values. Now I want to change this column to have just 2 values and this column is not nullable anymore:

```
Paid column
---
NotPaid = 0
Paid = 1
```

So if the value was NULL it's going to be `NotPaid`, `PaidTill` becomes `Paid` and so on.

I understand I can just extend `Up()` method with the data manipulation SQL but will this migration be revertable?

Answer (score 2):

The data manipulation you describe clearly loses data. Reverting it is impossible unless you can deduct the original values based on other data in your system.

If you don't have the other data, you can create it as part of the migration. Backup the original values in the `Up` method (copy to a separate column/table/schema/database). In the `Down` method, read the original values from the backup, and remove the backup:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    // before any manipulations:
    // create a backup table and copy data from the original column
    // assuming MyId is the primary key in the original table

    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
        SELECT *
        INTO MyNewBackupTable
        FROM (SELECT MyId, MyNullableColumn FROM MyOriginalTable)
    "); 

    // ... perform the desired manipulations 
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    // ... revert other manipulations,
    // (including making the column nullable again)

    // update the column from the data in the backup table
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
        UPDATE MyOriginalTable
        SET t1.MyNullableColumn = t2.MyNullableColumn
        FROM MyOriginalTable AS t1
        INNER JOIN MyNewBackupTable AS t2
        ON t1.MyId = t2.MyId 
    ");

    // remove the backup table
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"DROP TABLE MyNewBackupTable");
}
```

You can also delete the backup in one of subsequent migrations (`Up`) if the requirements allow you defining a "point of no return".